# expression must have pointer type

Tags: c, struct

I have a problem,the program gives an error like "expression must have pointer type".Can you help me ?

```
struct stack{
    int i_data;
    char c_data;
    struct stack *next;
}top;

void push_i(struct top *newptr,int info){  

    newptr=(struct top*)malloc(sizeof(top));

    if(newptr!=NULL){
        top->c_data=NULL;
        newptr->i_data=info;
        newptr->next=*top;
        *top=newptr;
    }
```

Comment: There is so much more wrong with this code. Why are you passing in newptr at all? If the intent is to return tha allocated memory then it should be ** and all instances of newptr in the function should be *newptr, there is just so wrong here if everyline in the code is broken.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Have you set a breakpoint somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You're mixing the *type* `struct stack` with the *variable* `top`
- Your `top` variable isn't a pointer, you can't change what it points at.
- `c_data` isn't a pointer, so don't assign `NULL` to it.
- You're not using the passed `newptr` for anything useful - it should be a local variable,.

This may work better:

```
struct stack{
    int i_data;
    char c_data;
    struct stack *next;
};

...
struct stack * top = NULL; 
...
void push_i(int info){  

    struct stack * newptr=(struct stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));

    if(newptr!=NULL){
        top->c_data=0;
        newptr->i_data=info;
        newptr->next=top;
        top=newptr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newptr->next = top
top = newptr
```

Remember, if x is declared T*, then x is the pointer, and *x is T. This is really not hard to understand. You want to assign the pointer, not overwrite where the pointer points.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your 'struct stack', thats the description of the structure.
Next loop at top, that's an instance of your structure. You appear to be mixing the both.
There shouldn't be any 'struct top' anywhere, they should be 'struct stack'.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems. The 1st is you are using the type `top` rather than the variable `newptr`.

Also you might want to be using **newptr when passing the variable in.